# Почему при создании опции в SlashCommands выдает ошибки

Tags: python, discord.py

```
import sqlite3
import discord

from discord.ext import commands
from discord_slash.utils.manage_commands import create_option
from settings import *

@slash.slash(name="First options", description="Первая сделаная опция мною",
         options=[
             {
                'name': 'text',
                'description': 'Введи какой угодно текст',
                'required': True,
                'type': 3  # str 3, int 4, user 6, role 8
             },
             ])
async def _first(ctx, SlashContext, text):
    await ctx.send(embed=discord.Embed(title=f"Я знаю что ты написал: {text}", 
colour=colors['green']))

@slash.slash(name="test",
             description="This is just a test command, nothing more.",
             options=[
              create_option(
                name="optone",
                description="This is the first option we have.",
                option_type=3,
                required=False
              )
         ])
async def test(ctx, optone: str):
    await ctx.send(content=f"I got you, you said {optone}!")
```

При запуске бота выскакивают ошибки, которые не позволяют запускать эти команды.
Ошибки выглядят так:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished name='Task-1' coro=<SlashCommand.sync_all_commands() done, defined at 
C:\Users\User\Desktop\Testovi boti\venv\lib\site-packages\discord_slash\client.py:415> 
exception=HTTPException('400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body\nIn name: 
String value did not match validation regex.')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Testovi boti\venv\lib\site-packages\discord_slash\client.py", line 
491, in sync_all_commands
raise ex
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Testovi boti\venv\lib\site-packages\discord_slash\client.py", line 
471, in sync_all_commands
existing_cmds = await self.req.put_slash_commands(
File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Testovi boti\venv\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 254, in 
request
raise HTTPException(r, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In name: String value did not match validation regex.
```

Answer (score 0):

**В тексте ошибки**

```
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 50035): Invalid Form Body
In name: String value did not match validation regex.
```

есть небольшая *подсказка* - `In name`, что указывает нам на то, что ошибка где-то в имени. Возможно в имени `слеш-команды` или в названии `функции` для слеш-команды.

Если изучить ошибку дальше, можно понять, что работе **мешает пробел** в названии вашей слеш-команды.

Достаточно его убрать и все запустится :)

```
# ошибка
name="First options"
# нет ошибки
name="First_options"
```